# Jquery Kinetic disable vertical touch swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery kinetic to provide horizontal swipe for my image containers.
However the problem is it is capturing vertical touch swipe as well and not letting me move downwards on the page.

I want kinetic to capture horizontal touch and let the browser handle vertical drags to move up/down the page.

I tried following the documentation and here is the code I have.

Approach 1

```
  var $scroller = $('.outer-container').kinetic();
  $('.outer-container').kinetic('y',{false});
```

Approach 2:

```
  var $scroller = $('.outer-container').kinetic();
    $('.outer-container').kinetic(filterTarget,function(y){
      return false;
    });
```

None of them seem to be working,I am sure I am missing something obvious as this is something many developers would have solved already.
Thanks